# AngularJS: enable button on form input change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have an app with a lot of settings in long form pages. You are expected to go to the pages to view the current settings, or to update them.

I would like to make it so that the "update" button is only enabled if someone actually changes the current inputs.

My naive approach would be to add an ng-change attribute to every input that sets the enableButton flag

```
<form name='form' ng-submit="submit()">
   <input type="sometype" ng-model='something1' ng-change="formChanged=true"></input>
   ...
   <input ng-model='somethingN' ng-change="formChanged=true"></input>
   <button ng-disabled="!formChanged" type="submit" />
</form>
```

but this seems tedious and repetitive (we have a lot of options), and was hoping for something simple  (something like "form.$hasChanged"...)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of setting a flag n change of any input of form, you should use the angular built in [`$dirty`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$dirty) property on the form controller object. It tells whether the user has interacted with the form's elements.

```
<form name='form' ng-submit="submit()">
   <input name="some1" type="sometype" ng-model='something1' ></input>
   ...
   <input name="some2" ng-model='somethingN' ></input>
   <button ng-disabled="!form.$dirty" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Using `$pristine` flag you could do

```
<button ng-disabled="form.$pristine" type="submit" />
```

Similarly if you have validators on the form you could as well make use of `$valid` property, example disable the button if the form is invalid or pristine

```
<button ng-disabled="form.$pristine|| form.$invalid" type="submit" />
```

Comment: So what if the user actually makes the form $dirty but then deletes the change. is it possible to check to see if there is actually a change in the fields before enabling the button

Comment: @Flash did you get an answer on this?

Comment: @HimalayMajumdar I ended up installing this library:
https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified
it worked perferctly